# How Do I Write This Nested Query With Expression Trees?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, subquery

### Motivation

I have a LINQ-to-SQL query that I need to write for production code involving generics and dynamic types. With the help of others on SO, I've been able to determine that I need to create the query using expression trees. In order to get familiar with expression trees, I'm trying to write a simpler statically typed version first, but I'm having trouble figuring out the nested query part.

I've been using MSDN as a reference, primarily [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx).

### Type

This is the type that will be used in the example query. It's a simplified version of a class used to create a grid with a dynamic number of columns from an SQL database.

```
public class PivotElement {
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string DataField { get; set; }
    public string ColumnText { get; set; }
}
```

### Resulting Query

This is the query I would like to eventually build, written in extension syntax:

```
IQueryable<PivotElement> iQ = ...;
var copy = iQ;

// filterColumn and filterValue are strings that were passed in

copy = copy.Where( 
    pe1 => theIQ.Where( 
        pe2 => 
            pe1.Key == pe1.Key && 
            pe2.DataField == filterColumn && 
            pgr2.ColumnText.Contains( filterValue )
    ).Any()
);
```

This query filters out rows that don't contain the requested text in the requested column before the elements have been pivoted.

### So Far

This is what I've got so far. I think it's mostly right, but I'm not sure how to indicate that the inner `Where` should always be called on `theIQ`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace IQueryableWhereTypeChange {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            var list = new List<PivotElement>() {
                new PivotElement() {
                    Key = 1, DataField = "FirstName", ColumnText = "Bob"
                },
                new PivotElement() {
                    Key = 1, DataField = "LastName", ColumnText = "Sanders"
                },
                new PivotElement() {
                    Key = 2, DataField = "FirstName", ColumnText = "Bob"
                },
                new PivotElement() {
                    Key = 2, DataField = "LastName", ColumnText = "Smith"
                },
                new PivotElement() {
                    Key = 3, DataField = "FirstName", ColumnText = "John"
                },
                new PivotElement() {
                    Key = 3, DataField = "LastName", ColumnText = "Smith"
                }
            };


            var theIQ = list.AsQueryable();
            var iQCopy = theIQ;

            var elementType = typeof( PivotElement );
            var delegateType = typeof( Func<PivotElement, bool> );

            var filterColumn = "LastName";
            var filterValue = "Smith";

            // Query is
            // iQCopy = iQCopy.Where( 
            //    pe1 => iQ.Where( 
            //        pe2 => 
            //            pe1.Key == pe1.Key && 
            //            pe2.DataField == filterColumn && 
            //            pgr2.ColumnText.Contains( filterValue )
            //    ).Any()
            //);

            // So all the elements for keys 2 and 3 should be in the
            //  result set, as those keys have a last name of Smith

            // build pe1
            Type elementType = typeof( PivotElement );
            ParameterExpression pe1 = Expression.Parameter( elementType, "pe1" );
            // build pe2
            ParameterExpression pe2 = Expression.Parameter( elementType, "pe2" );

            // pe1.Key
            Expression pe1KeyProp = Expression.Property( 
                pe1, elementType.GetProperty( "Key" )
            );
            // pe2.Key
            Expression pe2KeyProp = Expression.Property( 
                pe2, elementType.GetProperty( "Key" )
            );
            // build pe1.Key == pe2.Key
            Expression keyEquals = Expression.Equal( pe1KeyProp, pe2KeyProp );

            // build pe2.Datafield
            Expression pe2Datafield = Expression.Property( 
                pe2, elementType.GetProperty( "DataField" )
            );
            // build pe2.DataField == filterColumn
            Expression columnExpression = Expression.Constant( filterColumn );
            Expression dataEquals = Expression.Equal( 
                pe2Datafield, columnExpression 
            );

            // build pe2.ColumnText
            Expression pe2ColumnText = Expression.Property( 
                pe2, elementType.GetProperty( "ColumnText" )
            );
            // build pe2.ColumnText.Contains( filterValue )
            Type stringType = typeof(string);
            Expression valueExpression = Expression.Constant( filterValue );
            Expression textContains = Expression.Call( 
                pe2ColumnText, 
                stringType.GetMethod(
                    "Contains", 
                    new Type[] { stringType } ), 
                    new Expression[] { valueExpression }
            );

            // build pe1.Key == pe2.Key &&
            //       pe2.DataField == filterColumn && 
            //       pe2.ColumnText.Contains( filterValue )
            Expression innerCondition = Expression.AndAlso(
                keyEquals, Expression.AndAlso( dataEquals, textContains )
            );

            // build theIQ.Where( pe2 => innerCondition )
            // build theIQ.Where( pe2 => innerCondition ).Any()
            // build iQCopy.Where( pe1 => anyCall )
            // create the final query

            // enumerate results
            foreach( var pe in results ) {
                Console.WriteLine( 
                    "Key: " + pe.Key + 
                    ", DataField: " + pe.DataField + 
                    ", ColumnText: " + pe.ColumnText 
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public class PivotElement {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string DataField { get; set; }
        public string ColumnText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing bit hit me as I was getting that question all formatted. Since I already had it all typed up, I went ahead and posted it. Here are the missing bits, if anyone is interested:

```
// build theIQ.Where( pe2 => innerCondition )
Type queryableType = typeof( Queryable );
var delegateType = typeof( Func<PivotElement, bool> );
MethodCallExpression innerWhere = Expression.Call( 
    queryableType, 
    "Where", 
    new Type[] { elementType }, 
    new Expression[] { 
        theIQ.Expression, 
        Expression.Lambda(
            delegateType, innerCondition, new ParameterExpression[] { pe2 } 
        )
    } 
);

// build theIQ.Where( pe2 => innerWhere ).Any()
MethodCallExpression anyCall = Expression.Call( 
    queryableType, "Any", new Type[] { elementType }, innerWhere 
);

// build iQCopy.Where( pe1 => anyCall )
MethodCallExpression outerWhere = Expression.Call( 
    queryableType, 
    "Where",
    new Type[] { elementType }, 
    new Expression[] { 
        iQCopy.Expression, 
        Expression.Lambda( 
            delegateType, anyCall, new ParameterExpression[] { pe1 } 
        )
    }
);

// create the final query
var results = iQCopy.Provider.CreateQuery<PivotElement>( outerWhere );
```

The `theIQ.Expression` is what tells it to use query structure from `theIQ`, `iQCopy.Expression` is what tells it to use query structure from `iQCopy`, and the final `iQCopy.Provider` is what tells it to apply the constructed query to the actual `iQCopy` instance.